# Can I wrap a <li> element in an <a> with Markdown syntax?

Tags: web, markdown

I'm trying to produce the html:

```
<ul>
  <a href="#1"><li>item 1</li></a>
  <a href="#2"><li>item 2</li></a>
</ul>
```

And so on. I tried the following Markdown:

```
[* item 1](#1)
[* item 2](#2)
```

But it produces an altogether different effect.

Perhaps I'm outside problem space of Markdown, but it'd be awesome if I could do this!

Comment: I'd be interested to know why you wanna do such a thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not, since that's not valid HTML. `a` is not a valid direct child of `ul`.

From the [article about the UL element on W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) in the HTML5 documentation:

> #### 4.5.6 The ul element
>
> **Categories**
>   [Flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#flow-content).
>
> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
>   Where [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#flow-content) is expected.
>
> **Content model:**
>   Zero or more li elements.
>
> **Content attributes:**
>   [Global attributes][4]
>
> **DOM interface:**
>   `interface HTMLUListElement : HTMLElement {};`

As you can see in the *Content Model* description, nothing of `a` is mentioned. Instead, the correct output you're looking for is

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#1">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2">item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Which can easily be done in Markdown with

```
- [item 1](/#1)
- [item 2](/#2)
```

Which would look like

> - [item 1](/#1)
> - [item 2](/#2)

---

**Update**   I just realized that you're trying to create relative hashtag links, something I don't believe to be possible with Markdown.

Comment: The reason I was trying to do it was so that mousing over any part of the area of the <li> element would make active `:hover` behaviours and allow clicking on the link. I've seen it done on a whole bunch of sites and didn't realise it was invalid HTML. How naughty! I guess I'll have to do it some other way. Any tips for how I could achieve this with CSS?

Comment: What you have seen is just CSS. You can easily make an entire row appear as a link with CSS. Simply remove the list style from the _<li>_ element and add it to the _<a>_ element: `li { display: block; } li a { display: list-item; }`.